# How to permanently get the OneDrive API download address

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/permission_delete?view=odsp-graph-online

Note: The @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl value is a short-lived URL and can't be cached. The URL will only be available for a short period of time (1 hour) before it is invalidated.

In the tutorial, the download url expires after an hour. How do I get a permanent download address?

error Message

Sorry, something went wrong
The access token has expired. It's valid from '11/11/2020 1:18:52 AM' and to '11/11/2020 2:18:52 AM'.

Comment: Do you mean that the access token becomes unavailable after 1 hour?

Comment: @CarlZhao Sorry, something went wrong
The access token has expired. It's valid from '11/11/2020 1:18:52 AM' and to '11/11/2020 2:18:52 AM'.

Comment: When I click the download url I get that error.

Comment: Hmm... This is a very common error. The lifetime of an access token is 1 hour. Have you tried to use the refresh token to obtain a new access token, or customize the lifetime of the access token?

Comment: @carlZhao 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0

I only received the download url after request.

Comment: Please try the same as suggested above by Carl. You need to use the refresh token to obtain a new access token or customize the lifetime of the access token. Here's the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: The @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl value is a short-lived URL and can't be cached. The URL will only be available for a short period of time (1 hour) before it is invalidated. Removing file permissions for a user may not immediately invalidate the URL.

The workaround was to create a share link for DriveItem and use the WebUrl as the result of the response.
The file was accessed and made available for download through WebUrl.
It seemed that the only way for non-tenant users to access it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"The lifetime of an access token is 1 hour. Have you tried to use the refresh token to obtain a new access token, or customize the lifetime of the access token?"

Please try the same as suggested above by Carl. You need to use the refresh token to obtain a new access token or customize the lifetime of the access token. Here's the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
We created a share link and made it possible to download it with WebUrl. Tokens could not be obtained because anonymous users had to be able to download them.